# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition Error (I have checked it and the table definition/number is the same)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep receiving this error even though I have checked the table definition and the number of columns. It is definitely not an issue with the number of columns, I think it is more an issue with the types I am declaring.

/// Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.  ///

Can anyone spot a major mistake I am doing?

```
Create TABLE #tempResults 
 ( 
 [DateCreatedInvoiced] DATETIME,
 [Destination Country] VARCHAR (30), 
 [Destination Depot] VARCHAR (30),
 MovementRef VARCHAR (50),
 [Total Chargeable UK] INT,
 [Total Chargeable OS] INT,
 [Total Chargeable] INT,
 [Total AQ] INT,
 [Total FAM Allocation] INT,
 [Total Transport Cost] INT,
 TotalAmetaColDelCost INT,
 AQDepotDepot INT,
 TotalCons int,
 [SailingDate] DATETIME,
 [TrailerNumber] VARCHAR (150),
 [Count of Cons on Movement] VARCHAR (50),
 [INVOICED/NON-INVOICED] VARCHAR (50)
 )
 INSERT INTO #tempResults
 SELECT 
 Max(Cast(ME.InvoicedDate AS DATETIME)) AS [DateCreatedInvoiced], --1
 CR.DestinationCountry  AS [Destination Country] , --2
 ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '/' + COALESCE(cr.DestinationDepot, 'NA')    FOR
                   XML PATH('')
                 ), 1, 1, ''), '')  AS [Destination Depot], --3
 CASE
     WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')) > 0 THEN STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', ''), PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')), 10), 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-')
     ELSE ME.MovementReference
 END AS MovementRef , --4
CAST(SUM(CASE
     WHEN Payable = 'UK' THEN ME.ChargeableWeight
     ELSE 0
 END) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Chargeable UK], --5
CAST(SUM(CASE
     WHEN Payable = 'OS' THEN ChargeableWeight
     ELSE 0
 END) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Chargeable OS], --6
CAST(SUM(ChargeableWeight) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Chargeable], --7
CAST(SUM(AQCost) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total AQ], --8
CAST(SUM(FAMAllocation) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total FAM Allocation], --9
CAST(SUM(NottsHaulage + NottsHandling + NottsDistribution + ThurrockDistribution + ThurrockHandling) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Transport Cost],--10
CAST(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE
                           WHEN PartnerCurrency = 'GBP' THEN AmetaColDelCost
                           ELSE AmetaColDelCost / AmetaExchangeRate
                       END)) as Decimal (18,2)) AS TotalAmetaColDelCost, --11
CAST(SUM(AQDepotDepot) as Decimal (18,2)) AS AQDepotDepot, --12
Cast(COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) as INT) AS TotalCons, --13
MAX(MM.SailingDateTime) AS [SailingDate], --14
MAX(MU.Number) AS [TrailerNumber], --15
CASE
 WHEN COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) < 3 THEN 'Movement has 3 or less cons'
 ELSE 'Movement has 3 or more cons'
END AS [Count of Cons on Movement], --16
'Invoiced' AS [INVOICED/NOT-INVOICED] --17
```

Comment: There is no `FROM table_name` in your select query ?!! And your `create table` gives `syntax error in MySQL`.

Comment: I would also explicitly name the columns you are inserting to in your temp table INSET INTO #tempResults ( DateCreatedInvoiced, [Destination Countr], ....)

Comment: sql-server i guess.

Comment: @Leonidas199x thanks for the suggestion! DO you mean that I should give aliases to the columns in the insert into?

Comment: @KeyorPanchal - it's sql server! My mistake. Should I add the rest of the query here?

Comment: @Diana no, not aliases, I mean, you are not explicitly stating where the data is going, you are just saying INSERT INTO and then giving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a check try doing a

```
 SELECT
 Max(Cast(ME.InvoicedDate AS DATETIME)) AS [DateCreatedInvoiced], --1
 CR.DestinationCountry  AS [Destination Country] , --2
 ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '/' + COALESCE(cr.DestinationDepot, 'NA')    FOR
               XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, ''), '')  AS [Destination Depot], --3
 CASE
 WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')) > 0 THEN STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', ''), PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')), 10), 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-')
    ELSE ME.MovementReference
END AS MovementRef , --4
CAST(SUM(CASE
 WHEN Payable = 'UK' THEN ME.ChargeableWeight
 ELSE 0
END) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Chargeable UK], --5
CAST(SUM(CASE
     WHEN Payable = 'OS' THEN ChargeableWeight
 ELSE 0
END) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Chargeable OS], --6
CAST(SUM(ChargeableWeight) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Chargeable], --7
CAST(SUM(AQCost) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total AQ], --8
CAST(SUM(FAMAllocation) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total FAM Allocation], --9
CAST(SUM(NottsHaulage + NottsHandling + NottsDistribution + ThurrockDistribution + ThurrockHandling) as Decimal (18,2)) AS [Total Transport Cost],--10
CAST(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CASE
                       WHEN PartnerCurrency = 'GBP' THEN AmetaColDelCost
                       ELSE AmetaColDelCost / AmetaExchangeRate
                   END)) as Decimal (18,2)) AS TotalAmetaColDelCost, --11
CAST(SUM(AQDepotDepot) as Decimal (18,2)) AS AQDepotDepot, --12
Cast(COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) as INT) AS TotalCons, --13
MAX(MM.SailingDateTime) AS [SailingDate], --14
MAX(MU.Number) AS [TrailerNumber], --15
CASE
 WHEN COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) < 3 THEN 'Movement has 3 or less cons'
 ELSE 'Movement has 3 or more cons'
END AS [Count of Cons on Movement], --16
'Invoiced' AS [INVOICED/NOT-INVOICED] --17

INTO #TMPTABLE
FROM <YOUR_TABLE>


exec tempdb..sp_help '#TMPTABLE'
```

And then do a comparison of what columns are generated as compared to what you are scripting for the table.